# replacing all integers in one list, with strings in another

Tags: python

```
testdeck = ['rock']
finaldeck = ['apple','banana','napalm','ice',5,6,7,8]

def deckhelp(testdeck,finaldeck):
    testnumber = 0 
    testlength = len(testdeck)
    for index, (card, item) in enumerate(zip(testdeck, finaldeck)):
        if isinstance(item, int): #checks if item is an integer
            finaldeck[index] = card
            print(finaldeck)
            testnumber += 1
            if testnumber == testlength:
                print('done')
                pass

deckhelp(testdeck,finaldeck)
```

I want rock to replace the 5 located in finaldeck, can't seem to make it happen

Comment: `zip()` stops when the shortest input list runs out. So the loop only runs one time, because `testdeck` has just one element.

Comment: Why not trying - ```finaldeck[4:5] = testdeck```   since you already know the *position*?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an appropriate use of `zip()` because you only want to iterate through `testdeck` when you reach the integers in `finaldeck`.

You also need to use `return`, not `pass`, to end the function when you reach the end of `testdeck`.

```
def deckhelp(testdeck, finaldeck):
    testindex = 0
    testlength = len(testdeck)
    for index, item in enumerate(finaldeck):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            finaldeck[index] = testdeck[testindex]
            testindex += 1
            if testindex == testlength:
                print('done')
                return
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip only works in testdeck and finaldeck have the same length. Instead, you can use something like this:

```
def deckhelp(testdeck, finaldeck):
    replace_index = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(finaldeck):
        if isinstance(val, int):
            finaldeck[i] = testdeck[replace_index]
            replace_index += 1
            if replace_index == len(testdeck):
                print("done")
                return
```